# Getting a list of Google Earth Engine datasets?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm writing a Google Earth Engine client and need a [list of datasets](https://code.earthengine.google.com/datasets) that I can simply parse. In the best case it includes information like the bands, name, id, description, source/copyright, ... I don't really want to parse it from the HTML file I linked to as this is pretty messy.

I found that there is an endpoint https://code.earthengine.google.com/rasters?q=keyword that is used by the GEE Code Editor Playground. Is there any way to access this from outside the Playground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are exporting them to gs://earthengine-stac/catalog/catalog.json in STAC format (https://github.com/radiantearth/stac-spec)